Best metric to assess similarity between flight trajectories features
Consider a flight as represented by a dataframe with spatial (latitude, longitude, altitude) and temporal (timestamp) coordinates. Along the flight I have a variable tracking the length of the previous segment spent in some specific condition (e.g. temperature above a certain threshold), accumulatedMilesWithCondition:



latitude
longitude
timestamp
altitude
accumulatedMilesWithCondition
node




-17.5456
-149.5954
2020-06-01 21:00:00.000
5.0853
0.00
DEPARTURE


-17.5543
-149.6081
2020-06-01 21:00:33.300
43.1430
10.54
INTERMEDIATE


--
--
--
--
--
--


-22.0070
166.1995
2020-06-02 04:50:29.300
-23.3268
1140.58
DESTINATION



I simulated the same flight (same departure, destination, start time) with slightly different conditions, which leads to dataframes having slightly different spatial (besides from departure and destination, obviously) and temporal coordinates.
I want to derive a metric that would give me an estimation of how "similar" the variable accumulatedMilesWithCondition is between different flights. For example, here I'm comparing 3 different versions of the same flight using a color mapping that highlights the areas where accumulatedMilesWithCondition is increasing (that is, the areas where my condition is satisfied).

The idea would be to have a metric that gives a more quantitative idea on how these "images" are visually similar.
I've been experimenting with various metrics but the problem is that in all these cases I always need to somehow resample to a common index and this is hard to do because the only invariant of these flights is the departure and destination coordinates, while the rest can evolve freely (although, as I said, usually differences are really small). This means that also the number of points for some flights may be different.
Do you have some ideas regarding strategies to compare characteristics of different flight trajectories?

I think a variational autoencoder (VAE) with a 1D convolutional encoding stage might work.
The 1D convolutional encoding stage would be able to encode trajectory data that is long, multivariate, and of variable length.
Situating this in a VAE architecture would mean the network learns a representation of samples such that similar samples would be situated close together in that space.
This is just like dimensionality reduction, where you can project data into a 2D space and find that related samples cluster together. The complexity for this particular task arises from the data's structure, where we need to handle the variable sequence lengths amongst other things.
Suppose you train such a net, and then want to measure the similarity of two new trajectories. You'd pass them both through the encoder and read off their encodings. You can then compute the distance between the encodings (a scalar $d\ge0$), and interpret it as a dissimilarity measure.
